How do I read a struct contents in a running process?
I compiled a C binary on a linux machine and executed it, in that binary I have a struct called Location defined as follows
typedef struct 
{
    size_t x;
    size_t y;
} Location;

and here is my main function
int main(void)
{
    srand(0);
    Location loc;
    while (1)
    {
        loc.x = rand()%10;
        loc.y = rand()%10;
        sleep(2);
    }
    return 0;
}

How do I monitor the values of x and y?
There are some limitations to consider

I can't modify the binary code
monitoring should be done with python
ASLR always enabled

Things I tried

Reading /proc/pid/maps location stack then reading /proc/pid/mem didn't find anything
I used gdb to find the address of loc but it is outside the range of stack found in maps (most probably ASLR)


If you attach to the process with gdb you should be able to access it.

It's possible that the compiler has optimized it away, since you never use the value.

"monitor" ? What do you mean? Please be specific!

To check what @Barmar is saying, look at the generated assembly language file for the compilation command you're using.

To avoid optimizing loc out, consider Location loc; --> volatile Location loc;.  But I suppose that goes against I can't modify the binary code.

@Barmar isn't the while loop using loc

@TedLyngmo by monitor I mean keep track of the values, reading them every N seconds using the python script

@WeedCookie Ok, then what Barmar and the others are saying is what you should pay attention too. From a C compiler's perspective, there would not be any observable difference if what happens to loc was completely removed from the program, leaving you with while(1) { sleep(2); }

It's assigning to it, but never reading it. So the assignments are useless and can be removed.

We know the location is located in the stack somewhere, open maps file calculated stack size, start and end address, then open memory file in bytes mode and read stack bytes, loop over the bytes until you find a bytes sequence that maps to a given struct.
PS I have to add a third attribute to struct for sake of making the struct easier to find, will remove it in my actual code.
import sys
import ctypes



class Location(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("x", ctypes.c_size_t),
        ("y", ctypes.c_size_t),
        ("z", ctypes.c_size_t)
    ]



pid = sys.argv[1]

with open(f"/proc/{pid}/maps", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if "[stack]" in line:
        start, end = line.split()[0].split("-")

start = int(start, 16)
end = int(end, 16)

loc_size = ctypes.sizeof(Location)

with open (f"/proc/{pid}/mem", "rb") as f:
    f.seek(start)
    data = f.read(end-start)

print (len(data))
for i in range(0, len(data), loc_size):
    chunk = data[i:i+loc_size]
    if len (chunk) < loc_size:
        continue
    location = Location.from_buffer_copy(chunk)
    if location.z == 1337:
        print (f"\tx: {location.x}")
        print (f"\ty: {location.y}")
        print (f"\tz: {location.z}")


If you use srand(0), you will always get the same output, so why do you need to monitoring?
What do you mean by monitoring?
You can better save the values of x, y in a text file and then read the values from python.

srand(0) will ensure i get the same sequence of numbers every time i run the code but no the same numbers in rand()%10 which is useful when you want consistent results for testing. read about seeds.
